# Why my if check is not working in this code yet works in other separate file?

Tags: python, if-statement

My program outputs following:

> NA
> NA
> NA
> NA
> NA
> []
> []
> []
> []
> NA
> NA

[image]

and this is my if check:

```
if(firstname=='NA' and middlename=='NA' and lastname=='NA' and designtn=='NA' and psummary=='NA' and experiences==[] and companynames==[] and datesjoining==[] and uskills==[] and profileimage=='NA' and userlocation=='NA'):      
        self.proxyStatus2()
```

However, when I use this `if` condition, it doesn't return `true`, and the inner components don't get parsed. The condition seems fine to me.

I created a new Python file and created the same conditions there and it was working; yet, in this code, it doesn't work.

Comment: should be '[]'?

Comment: in the case where it does not work, are you running it from a notebook or from a larger script/function?
If that is the case you might want to check if any of the variables in the `if` statement are somehow overridden by you previous code/notebook. Maybe you have wrong values assigned in your namespace when it dos not work.